# Multiple Hibernate data sources

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a project that currently uses 3 databases on the same database server. One of the databases has now been moved to another physical server and I'm trying to get hibernate to handle this but struggling to work out where to start - should I duplicate datasource, sessionfactory, hibernatetemplate, and transaction manager and then try to manage this in the code? I'm using Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.5. Is this a common thing to do? Any advice would be much appreciated.

If it helps my config currently looks like this:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseOne"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>domain.DatabaseOneObject</value>
            <value>domain.DatabaseTwoObject</value>
            <value>domain.DatabaseThreeObject</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How can you manage 3 databases before? I am assuming you are already using 3 datasources, since as far as I know, one datasource can only be used with a database.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've used the incorrect terminology with Database rather than catalog. Currently I annotate the domain objects with `@Table(name="DatabaseTwoObject", catalog="DatabaseTwo")` still using a single data source

Comment: Why the database is moved to the other location?

Comment: We have a db server per client - 3 databases per server, 4 clients. The bottleneck on all servers is DatabaseThree so we've now got a 5th (high performance) server to host DatabaseThree and the other 4 servers will now have 2 databases on them

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use Sequoia (formerly [C-JDBC](http://c-jdbc.ow2.org/howdoesitwork.html)) to cluster your schemas from diferent databases into a single logical database.